# Closure that instantiate a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, closures

I wrote a JS simple class:

```
// JS simple class
class myClass
{
    constructor(init=0) { this.var = init; }    
    add(n) { this.var+=n; return this; }
    sub(n) { this.var-=n; return this; }
}
```

The class can be used with method chaining:

```
// Works well
obj1 = new myClass(0);
obj1.add(5);
obj1.sub(2);
console.log (obj1.var);

// Method chaining, works well
obj2 = new myClass(0);
obj2.add(9).sub(4).add(3);
console.log (obj2.var);
```

I would like to create a closure for convenience, thus the class could be used without explicitly creating a new object. For example, I would like something like:

```
obj(0).add(5).sub(2);
```

When calling `obj(0)`, a new instance of the class is created. I wrote the following closure, but the following does not work:

```
// Closure instantiating the class
var obj = function(init)
{
    var obj = new myClass(init)
    return { add:this.add, sub:this.sub };
}
```

When calling `obj(0).add(3);`, the following error is displayed in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: obj(...).add is not a function at window.onload ((index):58)
```

I don't know how to do this, and I'm even not sure the closure is the right tool.

Note that I already have a working solution without class (with closures), but I would like to keep my class.

I made a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/uatvx0kg/13/)

Comment: your obj function should just return the created class.
`function obj(init){return new myClass(init);}`

Comment: Waoo ... quite simply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fonction should return the new object:

```
// Closure instantiating the class
var obj = function(init)
{
    return  new myClass(init);
}
```

I updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/48mr2t5y/